# How do I automatically include the entity reference of an entity reference with JSON:API?

Tags: 9

My nodes of content type **Article** contain an entity reference to **Audio media**.  This **Audio media** has a file entity reference.

When listing articles via JSON:API, I want to automatically include this file entity reference for any articles that have it.

To auto-include the **Audio media** entity reference, I can use the JSON:API Defaults submodule of the [JSON:API Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) module to add `audioMedia` (JSON:API Extras customized name for the entity reference field pointing to **Audio media**).

However, I don't know how to auto-include the file entity reference, which is on the `audioMedia` entity reference.

I tried customizing the **Audio media** resource to include the file reference, but that includes it when accessing **Audio media** via JSON:API, not when accessing **Articles**.

I also tried adding `file` to the **Default include list** for **Articles**, but this gives an error that `file` is not an available option.

So how can I auto-include the entity reference of an entity reference with JSON:API Defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-level references need to be linked by a period:

`audioMedia.file`